# MySQL: When is it worth it to switch from basic field search (LIKE) to a FULLTEXT indexed search?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, innodb

I'm working on an application in which I need to search through the contents of a table for occurrences of a specific string, or a small set of strings in a column.

There are currently ~40K rows where the field in the LONGTEXT column I wish to search has an average length of 64 characters and a maximum length of 3500 characters (thus far). This table grows at a rate of roughly 6.5K rows per year.

Would adding a FULLTEXT index to enable FULLTEXT searching be the right thing to do in this situation, or will sticking with LIKE-based searching be quick enough? If the latter, how many rows would there need to be for it to be necessary to use a fulltext search?

Currently, when searching using 'LIKE' to search, I've not had a query run longer than 0.05s.

I'm currently using MySQL 5.5. The table uses the InnoDB engine. I'm aware that I would have to upgrade to MySQL 5.6 in order to use fulltext search on this table.

**NOTE:** I have no interest in tacking on a search engine, such as Elasticsearch. This is a very small feature of the application and it's not worth it to add the dependencies or the overhead.

**EDIT:** My LIKE-based queries are in the form of `WHERE column LIKE '%foobar%'`

Comment: It depends on your queries.  If you're only ever searching for prefixes, e.g. `WHERE column LIKE 'foobar%'`, then a normal B-Tree index on `column` will be perfectly sufficient; however if you're searching for words mid-string, e.g. `WHERE column LIKE '%foobar%'` then a `FULLTEXT` index will be beneficial (but only if `'foobar'` is a word-prefix - if it's to be found mid-word, you will have to look into third party indexing solutions).